# Como manter posicionamento da tela após postback?

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho um formulário html bem extenso com vários cadastros , depois de efetuar o `postback` minha página é redirecionada ao topo do formulário,como faço, para que quando for fazer o `postback` retornar na página de onde parei ?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa salvar o valor de `window.pageYOffset` (`document.documentElement.scrollTop` para IE8) e restaurar assim que sua página for carregada novamente.

Se estiver usando jQuery você pode fazer assim:

1. Adicionar um campo hidden para armazenar o valor do scroll

```
<form id="form1">
    ....
    <input type="hidden" name="scrollto" id="scrollto" value="0" />
</form>
```

2. O código abaixo salva o valor de `$.scrollTop` em `scrollto` no momento que o formulário é enviado e já restaura a posição do scroll quando a página é carregada.

```
$(function(){
  $('#form1').submit(function(){ 
     $('#scrollto').val( $(window).scrollTop() ); 
  });

  $(window).scrollTop( $('#scrollto').val() ); 
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou; O meu formulário contem 3 tipos de cadastro :Endereço,contato,veiculo, na mesma pagina ;cada form está separado em DIVs ,cada DIV faz parte da minha funcao javascript:    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    });
</script> essa funcao reparticiona o formulario e coloca em Abas!Modulos separados, visualmente melhorou muito mas,quando faço o Postback ela nao continua da ABA onde parei ,ela eh redirecionada para a 1ª ABA! O que faço????

Comment: Isso tudo em um form só?

Comment: Não cada ABA ,Cada Formulário tem seu form.

Comment: Então basta você colocar os ids dos forms separados por vírgulas no seletor (`$('#form1, #form2,....)'`), trocar o `id="scrollto"` por `class="scrollto"` e trocar o seletor `#scrollto` por `.scrollto` no código. Lembrando que você deve adicionar o input em todos os formulários.